# How can I find inverse for this functions?

Tags: functions, inverse

I have this function:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}$

with domain $a\leqslant x \leqslant b$, where $b>a>0$

I think its range is $(0,1)$. I am not able to figure out what is the rule for $f^{-1}(x)$ for general $a$ and $b$ and its *domain* and *range*.

Thanks [@Chris Custer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3588882/10840), I have arrived at following solution after looking around on the internet:

1. Substitute y for x:

   $y = \frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}$
2. Let $f^{-1}(x) = y$
3. $\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}$
4. using $g(f(x))$

   $g(\frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}) = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x\log_e\frac{b}{a}})\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}$
5. $g(\frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}) = \frac{1}{\frac{\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}}$
6. $g(\frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}) = x$
7. since $g(f(x)) =x$

   $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{x\log_e(\frac{b}{a})}$

**Question:** I'm not sure aobut step *4* though :(

Comment: When you replace $x$ by $f^-1 (x)$ and solve for $f^-1 (x)$, you would easily get the answer that $f$ is its own inverse, as suggested by Chris Custer.

Answer (score 1):

Interchange $x$ and $y$, and solve for $y$.  Get $x=\dfrac1{y\log_e(\frac ba)}\implies y=\dfrac1{x\log_e(\frac ba)}$.

Thus $f$ is its own inverse.

Comment: thanks Chris, I've put in the solution, I came up after watching videos, in the question. I've some doubt about step _4_.

Comment: You've got the right idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not comfortable unless I can understand or explain to someone why use `g(f(x))`

Comment: $g=f^{-1}$.  Thus $g(f(x))=f(g(x))=x$.

Comment: aha, bingo! that makes it easy and I can go to sleep. otherwise it felt very _unmathely_ like that we use this and here is the solution :D